# Team Foundation Server - Add rereference to existing dll to a new class library project

Tags: c#, tfs

I've just started using Team Foundation Server and have added a new Solution that contains a project of type class library.  I need to add a reference to the new class library project to an existing class library (dll) that we have created.  What is the best way to do this?  I've noticed that if I try to add it from the original location as an existing dll, it keeps the original location of the dll.  I think what I want is to actually copy the dll to the new project, and add a reference to it locally - but I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you include both the old and new projects in the same solution?  If so, you can reference the project directly (primary artifact) instead of the .dll output (secondary output).  This 'just works' when you need to build multiple configurations, such as debug, release, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Write a MSbuild/Nant script that build's and copies the dll to a common lib directory. Then reference the lib\foo.dll in 2nd project. Also create the build order.

Answer (score 0):

If that dll is something that will be shared among different libraries and applications, you may want to consider putting it in the GAC. This will also help avoid versioning issues of putting it in a common lib directory (although you could just put folders in the common lib directory for different versions)

MSDN article on the GAC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another way that doesn't involve copying the whole project or messing with the GAC would be to:

1. Add a reference to the DLL to your project
2. Open the references folder in your project
3. Right click the DLL -> Properties
4. Find Copy Local and set it to "True"